# How to using value with string

Tags: php

I wanna make currency converter.

```
$number1="";
$number3="";
<form method="POST">
   <select id="dc1" name="dc1">
      <option value="9777.31">SGD</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="text1" value="<?php echo $nilai1?>">

   <select id="dc2" name="dc2">
       <option value="13190" >USD</option>
        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">
   </select>
</form>
<?php     
if(isset($_POST['calculate']))     
{     
 if($_POST['dc1'] && $_POST['dc2'])    
 {  
    $number1 = $_POST['text1'];
    $one = $_POST['dc1'];
    $two = $_POST['dc2'];

    $x = $number1 / ($two/$one);
    $number3 = $x;
 }else{
     $number3 = "fail";
 }
} 
?> 
<input type="text" name="text2" value="<?php echo $number3?>">
```

its ok with these code, but when I am trying to change like this?

```
$number1="";
$number3="";
$test=9777.31;
<form method="POST">
   <select id="dc1" name="dc1">
      <option value="<?php $test?>">SGD</option>
   </select>
```

the `$number3` result is `"fail"`, its my code so bad? or I forgot something?

Comment: For a start you have an `input` tag inside a `select` block. And you have PHP code that's outside of PHP tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$number1="";
$number3="";
$test=9777.31;
<form method="POST">
   <select id="dc1" name="dc1">
      <option value="<?php echo $test?>">SGD</option>
   </select>
```